# Why is it that the <a href=...> tag to another section id isn't working?

Tags: html, reactjs

```
render() {
    <p><a href=#tag>Link</a></p>
    ....
    <div id="tag">{item.getContent()}</div>
}
```

I'm finding that clicking on the `Link` tag doesn't get make me jump to the section of the page I want. What gives?

Not sure if this is relevant but all this is in a `.jsx` file.

Comment: What happens if you put `href=#tag` in quotes: `<a href="#tag">`?

Comment: I tried that too. It doesn't work.

Comment: Does it have a scrollbar?

Comment: What router are you using? clicking on a link like that will trigger a hashchange, which could be being intercepted by your router logic.

Comment: Check that there are not other id attributes on the page that also have a value of "tag". They must be globally unique, or they will not work as expected.

Comment: make sure you are not returning multiple elements in the render method

Comment: The answer is that we are using a single page application where the user transitions between different screens without the server-side HTML refresh required by traditional web applications. I fixed it by adding to the `scrollTop` of the element that has the scroll.